# Shortcut key to find global variable inside a project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the shortcut key to find that where is the particular **global variable Initializing** in android studio project.

Comment: use SHIFT + SHIFT to search everywhere in your project

Answer (score 0):

Place your cursor on the variable and then press Alt+F7 for the Find Useages command. In the Find Usages result, look for "Value write". Expanding that category will show all the places where the variable is assigned, which includes initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you middle-mouse-click any of your variables it takes you to the delcaration. If you middle click it again, it pops up a window with every usage. Alt+F7 works too.